# Atom on Ubuntu not linting code using phpcs; same process works on macOS

Tags: ubuntu, atom-feed, lint

My goal here is to install a development environment on Ubuntu, I have most of the necessary parts but I am stuck on the last piece.

I am using Atom as the code editor and I want Atom to lint my code using phpcs as I type.

I have achieved this on macOS but the same process is not working on this installation of Ubuntu.

[image: Atom]

As you can see from the screenshot above, my code is not being linted at all.

I installed `linter` and `linter-phpcs` but the packages are not being used for some reason.  Does anyone know how to get Atom to use the packages and/or make the package get its ruleset from WordPress Coding Standards?